# Update AuthorId in sharepoint 2013 Blog

Tags: blog, client-object-model

In a sharepoint 2013 Blog site I am posting a post on behalf of few senior members of our organization. As usual it shows my name in posted by field.
Is there a way to change that programatically change the AuthorId.

I had tried the following code

```
<script src="/apps/test/Style%20Library/css%20files/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/apps/test/Style%20Library/css%20files/jquery.SPServices-2013.02a.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var siteUrl = '/apps/test/blog';

function updateListItem() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Posts');

    this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(5);

    oListItem.set_item('AuthorId', '22');

    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

    alert('Item updated!');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>
```

When I execute the above code it says,

> Request failed. Column 'AuthorId' does not exist. It may have been
>   deleted by another user.  /apps/opus/blog/Lists/Posts undefined

But When I read the same list using similar JS code I am able see AuthorId.
Please suggest a way to update/change AuthorId for a post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blogs list contains field `Author`(Title: `Created By`) and since it is a user field type, it value is represented by [SP.FieldUserValue object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246963.aspx) via JSOM.

### Solution

Replace the line:

```
oListItem.set_item('AuthorId', '22');
```

with

```
oListItem.set_item('Author', 22); //value corresponds to User Id
```

Comment: couldn't get this to work in foundation

Comment: I would recommend to create a separate question for this request